# Create "synthetic points"

Tags: python

I need to create inside a python routine, something that I am calling "synthetic points".

I have a series of data which vary between -1 and 1, however, when I put this data on a chart, they form a trapezoidal chart.
What I would like to do is create points where the same x-axis value, could take two y-axis values, and then, this will create a chart with 
straight lines making a "rectangular chart"

An example the format data that I have:

```
0;-1
1;-1
2;-1
3;-1
4;-1
5;-1
6;-1
7;1
8;1
9;1
10;1
11;1
12;1
13;1
14;1
15;1
16;-1
17;-1
18;-1
19;-1
20;-1
```

For example, in this case, I would need the data assume the following format:

```
0;-1
1;-1
2;-1
3;-1
4;-1
5;-1
6;-1
6;1 (point 6 with two values)
7;1
8;1
9;1
10;1
11;1
12;1
13;1
14;1
15;1
15;-1 (point 15 with two values)
16;-1
17;-1
18;-1
19;-1
20;-1
```

So what you need to do is, always when I had a value change, this will create a new point. This makes the graph, rectangular, as the only possible values for the y variable are -1 and 1.

The code I need to enter is below. What was done next was just to put the input data in this format of -1 and 1.

```
arq = open('vazdif.out', 'rt')
list = []
i = 0
for row in arq:
    field = row.split(';')
    vaz = float(field[2])
    if vaz < 0:
        list.append("-1")
    elif vaz > 0:
        list.append("1")
    n = len(list)  
fou = open('res_id.out','wt')
for i in range(n):
        fou.write('{};{}\n'.format(i,list[i])) 
fou.close
```

Thank you for your help

P.s. English is not my first language, forgive my mistakes  on write or on the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added a new value `prev_value`, if the previous value is of the opposite sign (multiply with the current value < 0), it adds an extra index to the list.

I think the `field[1]` and `field[2]` are probably wrong, but I'll trust your code works so far. Similar with `fou`, I would replace with `with open ...`

```
arq = open('vazdif.out', 'rt')
list = []
i = 0
prev_value = 0

for row in arq:
    field = row.split(';')
    xxx = int(field[1])
    vaz = float(field[2])

    if vaz * prev_value < 0:
        list.append([list[-1][0], - list[-1][1]])

    if vaz < 0:
        list.append([xxx, -1])
    else:
        list.append([xxx, 1])

    prev_val = vaz
fou = open('res_id.out','wt')
for i in list:
        fou.write(f'{i[0]};{i[1]}\n') 
fou.close
```

Comment: It's worked for me, i just changed the out format, for another
_fou.write('{};{}\n'.format(i[0],i[1]))_
. Thank you very much!

Comment: @NathanStreisky just noticed we have the same name ;), could you accept the answer as correct so others don't have to worry about it?